# How to input a string in VC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to input a string with VC, but it seems the getline function didn't work, when I run my program, the "cin" part was skipped. Here is my code

```
printf("Exercise 1\n");
    printf("Please enter the sentence you want\n");
    char str[256];
    std::cin.getline(str, 256);
    std::cout << str;
```

Here are my headers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
```

I'm using VS2015 community, is there anything wrong with my compiler?

Comment: `char str[256];` -> `std::string str;` , `std::cin.getline(str, 256);` -> `std::getline(std::cin, str);` and skies are blue again.

Comment: Get a different book.  You should be using `std::string` for *string* and text.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do?

```
char str[256];
std::cin >> str;
```

or

```
string mystring;
std::getline (std::cin,mystring);
```

Comment: Well, I did that before. But I need to count the word and characters in my string, and the blank space between two words need to be skipped. That's why I used getline function. So how can I do that?

Comment: BTW, `std::cin >> mystring` will only read a word.  To get the enter text line, `std::getline` must be used.

Comment: I see. Edited. Thanks for the comment @ThomasMatthews

Comment: @D.Kenny : For that, see the most voted(1800+) answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c and split strings later.